# What is the use of reentrant function in multi-threaded environment?

Tags: linux, multithreading

What is the use of reentrant function in multi-threaded environment ?

Comment: It means that it's safe for multiple threads to call the same function. This means that all variables should be local to the function, or that there's a thread-safe mechanism to access global variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Threads should use only `re-entrant` functions which are `thread-safe` to ensure data integrity and unpredictable behavior.

> All system calls and library functions which end with `_r` are
>   re-entrant or Mt-Safe functions for e.g `ctime_r`

See the manual page of `localtime()`

```
       ┌───────────────┬───────────────┬─────────────────────────────────┐
       │Interface      │ Attribute     │ Value                           │
       ├───────────────┼───────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
       │asctime()      │ Thread safety │ MT-Unsafe race:asctime locale   │
       ├───────────────┼───────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
       │asctime_r()    │ Thread safety │ MT-Safe locale                  │
       ├───────────────┼───────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
       │ctime()        │ Thread safety │ MT-Unsafe race:tmbuf            │
       │               │               │ race:asctime env locale         │
       ├───────────────┼───────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
       │ctime_r(),     │ Thread safety │ MT-Safe env locale              │
       │gmtime_r(),    │               │                                 │
       │localtime_r(), │               │                                 │
       │mktime()       │               │                                 │
       ├───────────────┼───────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
       │gmtime(),      │ Thread safety │ MT-Unsafe race:tmbuf env locale │
       │localtime()    │               │                                 │
       └───────────────┴───────────────┴─────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Thanks Achal. I go through this link also. Its nice one=> https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/489679/difference-between-thread-safe-and-reentrant

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you mean by "reentrant function."

A reentrant *call* to a function means that more than one [activation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack#Structure) of the function can exist at the same time.  There are several ways in which that could happen;  A function could call itself (i.e., it is a [recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion#In_computer_science) function), or it could be called by a [callback handler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)) for some library routine that it itself uses, or it could be called by an [interrupt handler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt).  Any of the above could result in more than one activation of the same function (i.e., there could be reentrant calls) on the same [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack).

If a function can be called by more than one thread, then there could be multiple activations of the function on different stacks.

Sometimes when we say "reentrant function," we are talking about a function that is *designed* to do the right thing even when more than one active call to it exists.  That is a desirable property for functions that are called in a multi-threaded environment where reentrant calls are very easy to achieve.  The simplest way to ensure that a function is safe for reentrant calls is to ensure that it does not access any [static variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable) or any [non-local variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-local_variable).